# WPF ListBox not updating when Bound List is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having a problem with my ListBox as it's not updating when I update the list it's bound to. I've already seen many of the same questions but none of it's answers solved my problem. My situation is that I have a ComboBox that when an option is selected, my ListBox will show options based on the ComboBox selection. I know that the list bound to the ListBox is being updated, but the items don't show on the list. If I manualy add an item on the declaration of the ViewModel class of the list than the item appear, but that's not what I want (or maybe it is and I'm seeing this from the wrong angle). Here's my code so far:

The VM for my ComboBox and the calling for updating the ListBox:

```
public class SelectorEventosViewModel : ObservableCollection<SelectorEvents>,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SelectorEvents _currentSelection;
    public SelectorEventosViewModel()
    {
        PopulaSelectorEvents();
    }

    private void PopulaSelectorEvents()
    {
        Add(new SelectorEvents {Key = "evtInfoEmpregador", Value = "S1000"});
        Add(new SelectorEvents {Key = "evtTabEstab", Value = "S1005"});
        Add(new SelectorEvents {Key = "evtTabRubricas", Value = "S1010"});
    }

    public SelectorEvents CurrentSelection
    {
        get => _currentSelection;
        set
        {
            if (_currentSelection == value)
                return;
            _currentSelection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentSelection));
            ValueChanged(_currentSelection.Key);
        }
    }
    //Here I detect selectiong and then call for the Update in my ListBox VM
    private void ValueChanged(string value)
    {
        EventFilesViewModel.Instance.GetFiles(value);
    }

    protected override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here's my code for the ListBox VM:

```
public class EventFilesViewModel : ObservableCollection<EventFiles>
{
    private static EventFilesViewModel _instance = new EventFilesViewModel();
    public static EventFilesViewModel Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new EventFilesViewModel());
    private string[] _filesList;
    //This would be my Update function, based on the ComboBox selection I would show some files in my ListBox, but it's not
    public void GetFiles(string ptr)
    {
        _filesList = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\mp-2624/c$/xampp/htdocs/desenv2/public/esocial/eventos/aguardando/");
        Clear();
        foreach (string file in _filesList)
        {
            var r = new Regex(ptr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var tempFiles = new EventFiles {Key = file, Value = file.Split('/')[9]};
            if (r.Match(file).Success)
            {
                Add(tempFiles);
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EventFilesViewModel));
    }

    protected override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My models SelectorEvents and FileEvents both implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

My XAML:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectorEventosViewModel}" Name="EventoBox" FontSize="20" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="20 10" Width="150" 
                                          ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectorEventosViewModel}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelection}"
                                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>

<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EventFilesViewModel}"
                                             Grid.Column="0" Name="EventoListBox" FontSize="20" Margin="10 10"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                             ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EventFilesViewModel}"
                                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                             DisplayMemberPath="Value">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your static resource reference in XAML look like?

Comment: Here they are: <viewModel:SelectorEventosViewModel x:Key="SelectorEventosViewModel"/>
        <viewModel:EventFilesViewModel x:Key="EventFilesViewModel"/>

Comment: You should only inherit from lists if you have something to add. Better use a property with the items.

Comment: For the ComboBox I agree that it should be static, but the ListBox is dynamic as it will be modified based on the ComboBox value

Comment: When you derive from ObservableCollection, do not add another INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Instead, use the one that is already there, and just call [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.onpropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1_OnPropertyChanged_System_ComponentModel_PropertyChangedEventArgs_)

Comment: I've removed the override, and used the OnPropertyChanged, sadly it didn't solved my problem.

Comment: It would be far easier at this point to define a VM for both controls, and initialize an instance as part of the control being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not certain how you intended to have this work, but here's a solution which is more MVVM.

Essentially we collapse both of your VM's into a MainWindowVm, which handles shuttling messages between the two. That way your child VM's remain independent of each other, and thus more configurable down the line.

Based on my testing the binding for your ItemSource on the second record was not succeeding (I added a button and examined the value for ItemSource at run time after confirming the EventFilesViewModel had been updated).

**EventFilesViewModel**

```
public class EventFilesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<EventFiles> EventFiles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<EventFiles>();

   private string[] _filesList;

   //This would be my Update function, based on the ComboBox selection I would show some files in my ListBox, but it's not
   public void GetFiles(string ptr)
   {
      _filesList = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\mp-2624/c$/xampp/htdocs/desenv2/public/esocial/eventos/aguardando/");
      EventFiles.Clear();
      foreach (string file in _filesList)
      {
         var r = new Regex(ptr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         var tempFiles = new EventFiles { Key = file, Value = file.Split('/')[9] };
         if (r.Match(file).Success)
         {
            EventFiles.Add(tempFiles);
         }
      }
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EventFilesViewModel));
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

**SelectorEventosViewModel**

```
public class SelectorEventosViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<SelectorEvents> SelectorEvents { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SelectorEvents>();

   private SelectorEvents _currentSelection;

   public SelectorEventosViewModel()
   {
      PopulaSelectorEvents();
   }

   private void PopulaSelectorEvents()
   {
      SelectorEvents.Add(new SelectorEvents { Key = "evtInfoEmpregador", Value = "S1000" });
      SelectorEvents.Add(new SelectorEvents { Key = "evtTabEstab", Value = "S1005" });
      SelectorEvents.Add(new SelectorEvents { Key = "evtTabRubricas", Value = "S1010" });
   }

   public SelectorEvents CurrentSelection
   {
      get => _currentSelection;
      set
      {
         if (_currentSelection == value)
            return;

         _currentSelection = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

**MainWindowVm.cs**

```
public class MainWindowVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public SelectorEventosViewModel SelectorEventosViewModel { get; } = new SelectorEventosViewModel();

   public EventFilesViewModel EventFilesViewModel { get; } = new EventFilesViewModel();

   public MainWindowVm()
   {
      // CRITICAL--ensures that your itemsource gets updated
      SelectorEventosViewModel.PropertyChanged += SelectorEventosViewModel_PropertyChanged;
   }

   private void SelectorEventosViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // CRITICAL--ensures that your itemsource gets updated
      EventFilesViewModel.GetFiles(SelectorEventosViewModel.CurrentSelection.Key);
   }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="_52370275.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_52370275"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowVm}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ComboBox
         Name="EventoBox"
         FontSize="20"
         SelectedIndex="0"
         Margin="20 10"
         Width="150"
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectorEventosViewModel.SelectorEvents}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Value"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectorEventosViewModel.CurrentSelection}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

      <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
               Name="EventoListBox"
               FontSize="20"
               Margin="10 10"
               Grid.Row="1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               ItemsSource="{Binding EventFilesViewModel.EventFiles}"
               IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
               DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new MainWindowVm();
   }
}
```

All together, this allows you to define the static values for your initial combobox in code-behind, and have the list box itemsource be updated.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. So analysing your code, I should have handled the update in a main VM that would trigger the update? I'm relatively new to this MVVM architecture

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind is that with MVVM the need for event handling based on selections changing goes down dramatically. With binding to properties on a VM, you gain the ability to change values on the VM directly without having to go through the rigamarole of "assign the selected value from the control named X to the property Y". It just happens directly and cuts out the middleman.

Comment: The best way to get started thinking in a MVVM fashion is to break your UI into concrete individual components. You had a good start with your two VM's you started with. What really helps though is to define a 'control' or 'window' level VM that handles orchestrating communication between them all. You could even have extracted the values and code from the two VM's and collapsed them into a single VM, but that might not have been ideal.